# AMQP Connection string to Active MQ using Elixir

Tags: amqp, elixir, qpid, erlang-shell

i am using ActiveMQ as message broker and used Qpid proton c library to connect to Erlang for messaging service and seems working well with below commands with ActiveMQ running.

```
qpidpn:subscribe("amqp://127.0.0.1/topic://destination").
qpidpn:publish(#{address => "amqp://127.0.0.1/topic://destination", body => "hello"}).
flush().
qpidpn:stop().
q().
```

I need to write a module in elixir to connect to the ActiveMQ broker same as done in erlang above.
Erlang is though connected to message broker service using qpid library. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried out the code below but calling an Erlang lib from Elixir is pretty trivial.

Try this:

```
:qpidpn.subscribe("amqp://127.0.0.1/topic://destination")
:qpidpn.publish(%{:address => "amqp://127.0.0.1/topic://destination", :body => "hello"})
:flush()
:qpidpn.stop()
:q()
```

As I say, I haven't tried it (and can't because I don't have amqp or qpidn installed) but that may be along the lines of what you're looking for.

Comment: flush() and q() are only available in Erlang shell. Those should not be needed in the module OP wants to write.